# Setting a background image to be full screen, and scrollable

Tags: html, css, image

I'm setting a landing page for [My new website](http://www.ontheropesboxing.com)

I've created an image, and I'm setting it as the background image.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out at all how to get it to be full screen, and scrollable - so you can just scroll up/down to see the full image - but without having any white spaces or anything.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <title>On The Ropes Boxing! Coming Soon!</title>

  <body>
<style>
html { 
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    background: url(comingsoon.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
}
#appcontainer {
    position: relative
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    width:560px; height:2220px;
    left:20px; top:20px;
}
    <img src="comingsoon.jpg" style="minwidth:100%;height:100%;" alt="" />
</style>
  </body>
</html>
```

That is what I have so far.  I'm completely new to HTML and CSS, so I'm basically just learning on the job and going through trial and error.  I fully expect to be told I'm doing this completely the wrong way.  Any advice is appreciated - just be aware that I may need to be told as if I'm an idiot :)

Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you always want the background larger than the resolution?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kUPQoFi.jpg Is the original image if that helps.

Comment: @NicholasHazel - I've no idea how to set it so it changes based on different resolutions.  My intention was for a horizontally fixed but vertically scrolling landing image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `img` tag in your code with this:
`<img src="http://www.ontheropesboxing.com/comingsoon.jpg" style="width:100%;position:absolute;z-index:-1" alt="" />`
And move it out of the `style` tags.

Comment: I just replaced the original line with yours, but it's still fixed vertically, without letting me scroll down.

Comment: I saw a spelling error in "absolute" - I corrected it and it now works perfectly.  Thanks so much - I really appreciate your help there.

Answer (score 0):

Before I get into the answer, allow me to correct your code first.

The basic format for a webpage is this:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        //Titles, scripts, styles, etc.
    </head>
    <body>
        //Everything else, can also hold scripts and styles.
    </body>
</html>
```

You're missing a `head` in your code.

Second, don't place html tags inside `style` tags (referring to your `img`).

As for your question,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>On The Ropes Boxing! Coming Soon!</title>
        <style>
            html, body { 
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin:0px;
                border: 0;
            }
            .splash {
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 0;
            }
            //Rest of styles
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://www.ontheropesboxing.com/comingsoon.jpg" class="splash" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Putting the image as the background won't work, as the page won't have anything to scroll to. Putting the background as an image will allow the page to scroll.

Comment: Thanks, in hindsight, it makes much more sense.  I was just googling, and putting things together that looked like it may work and it wasn't screwing up my page.  I appreciate the effort and the corrections - definitely learnt some things tonight :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that you don't need to put the image as both the background and a separate `img`.